# Yii2 Add a Form field not in model

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

As we know,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name_field')->textInput() ?>
```

Adds a text field connected to 'name_field' in the model/table.

I want to add a field NOT in the model/table, and then run some JS when it loses focus to calculate the other fields.

How firstly do you add a free text field not connected to the model ?
Second, does anyone have any examples of adding JS/Jquery to the _form.php ?

Comment: I usually don't use an `ActiveRecord`-instance but put a special form-model in between (can be a simple `Model`), especially for that sort of things. You can add as many custom fields as you want, add special form-only validation rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Html`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html) class contains the functions for generation of fields. In fact, your code above ends up calling [`Html::textInput()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textInput%28%29-detail). To add a field

```
<?= Html::textInput("name", $value) ?>
```

To add javascript to a view just use [`registerJs()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs%28%29-detail):

```
$this->registerJs("alert('true');");
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined variable:value. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the field rendered the same way as the ActiveField, with a label and classes. For example, let’s add a *Cc* field to a **Mail** form.

First display the To: field (in the model):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'to')->textInput() ?>
```

Let’s add the *Cc* field (not in the model):

```
<?= Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'form-group field-mail-cc']) ?>
<?= Html::label('Cc:', 'mail-cc', ['class' => 'control-label']) ?>
<?= Html::textInput('Mail[cc]', '', ['id' => 'mail-cc', 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= Html::endTag('div') ?>
```

The class and id names *mail-cc* and *field-mail-cc* follow the ActiveForm naming pattern. The input name Mail[cc] adds your field to the ActiveForm group, so you can easily retrieve it with the usual

```
$form = Yii::$app->request->post('Mail');
```